# Передача переменных из php в javascript без перезагрузки

Tags: ajax, html, javascript, php

предположим есть

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
```

оброботчик Test.php

```
<?php
 $a = "10";
 $b = "20";
?>
```

Необходимо поместить $a в div с id='1' и $b в div с id='2'! Без перезагрузки страници !

```
function getXmlHttp(){
  var xmlhttp;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}
```

и теперь нужно написать чтобы открывалось асинхронное соединение к фаилу Test.php, брало от туда значения переменных и засовывало их в

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

можно сделать передачу в формате json

```
<?php
    $a = "10";
    $b = "20";
    $arr = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
    echo json_encode($arr); /// {"a":"10", "b":"20"}
?>
```

Далее в js обработать как объект. Например если использовать jQuery, то

```
$.getJSON("Test.php",
    function(data){
        $("#a").html(data.a);
        $("#b").html(data.b);
    });
});
```

Еще синтаксическая ошибка в html

```
<!-- Имена идентификаторов должны начинатся с латинской буквы http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id -->
<div id='a'></div> 
<div id='b'></div>
```

Ну а если не jquery, то можно полученный запрос обработать так

```
function LoadDiv(){
    var req = getXmlHttp();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    { 
        if (req.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(req.status == 200)
            {
                var a = req.responseText;
                eval("b = "+a);
                if(typeof b == 'object')
                {
                    d = document;
                    d.getElementById('a').innerHTML =  b.a;
                    d.getElementById('b').innerHTML =  b.b;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error: "+a)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error: "+xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
    req.open('GET', 'Test.php'); 
    req.send(null);
}
```

Дополнение:
какя переменная? Если про b, то она является объектом:

1. От сервера приходит ответ {"a":"10", "b":"20"}
2. Этот ответ объявляем в переменной a
3. При помощи аргумента функции eval создаем выражение b = {"a":"10", "b":"20"} и соответственно эвалим его
4. У нас получился объект b со значениями b = {"a":"10", "b":"20"}
5. Проверяем дествительно ли сервер вернул объект if(typeof b == 'object')
6. Теперь этот объект используем (b.a = 10 и b.b = 20) для вставки в элементы div на странице  d.getElementById('a').innerHTML =  b.a; и d.getElementById('b').innerHTML =  b.b; (для справки вместо "1" и "2" я использовал дивы "a" и "b")
7. ??????
8. PROFIT

Пруфлинки:
http://javascript.ru/eval
http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/intro
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

если переменных надо больше дописываем в массиве в php сколько угодно и потом вынимаем их в javascript все указано выше.

Comment: <!-- Имена идентификаторов должны начинатся с латинской буквы http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id --> - я знаю я цифры поставил чтобы не запутатся 

а тут одна переменная повторяется несколько раз

                eval("b = "+a);
                if(typeof b == 'object')
                {
                    d = document;
                    d.getElementById('a').innerHTML =  b.a;
                    d.getElementById('b').innerHTML =  b.b;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error: "+a)

напишите пожалуста с цифрами а то я запутался :(

Comment: И что делать если переменных должно быть больше ?

Comment: ответ выше